# Add library to android studio

Tags: android, shared-libraries

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "jzdevelopers.ml.schoolbinder"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}

}

repositories {
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }

jcenter()
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:richedit:0.5.2'
compile 'org.sufficientlysecure:html-textview:1.4'
compile ('com.github.NightWhistler:HtmlSpanner:0.4')
compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.6@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile('com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
compile('com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4') {
    exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
  }
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt
>       File1: /Users/JordanZimmitti/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jdom/jdom/1.1/1d04c0f321ea337f3661cf7ede8f4c6f653a8fdd/jdom-1.1.jar
>       File2: /Users/JordanZimmitti/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.ant/ant/1.7.0/9746af1a485e50cf18dcb232489032a847067066/ant-1.7.0.jar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "[JitPack](https://jitpack.io/)", once integrated in gradle enter the link of the user and the name of his github repo.
For this specific case, so you should write:

```
compile 'com.github.NightWhistler:HtmlSpanner:0.4'
```

Of course in the repositories you add this line, as you will also find the official website

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

EDIT

Edit your build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "jzdevelopers.ml.schoolbinder"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}

}

repositories {
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }

jcenter()
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:richedit:0.5.2'
compile 'org.sufficientlysecure:html-textview:1.4'
compile 'com.github.NightWhistler:HtmlSpanner:0.4'
compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.6@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile('com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
compile('com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4') {
    exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
  }
```

Comment: you entered the order of the repositories in maven?
Then you entered in the dependency checking compile?
if you bring me the error
https://jitpack.io/

Comment: Test the new compile code: 
compile 'com.github.nightwhistler:HtmlSpanner:2.16'
for the version I'm not sure but the currently described and the page github (version 2.16).

Comment: here I updated version, now you should go.
compile 'com.github.NightWhistler:HtmlSpanner:0.4'

Comment: your the best! where did you get the 0.4 from i was looking for it

Comment: the version you find in the dropdown menu "Branch", to select them "tags" and see the versions

Comment: add this to buid.gradle in 
Android{
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' 
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' 
}
}

Comment: where in the build.gradle do I add that ill re add my build.gradle above

Comment: added that but got an error posted it above in update

Comment: you have to add the code in the Android tag {} already exists, so you have to add the lines inside.

Comment: I've inserted directly I rows in your file

Comment: check update I think I added it correctly stil getting error

Comment: I added .txt both license that notice :D

Comment: Hi peppinoibra I have another question about google drive api on another thread the link is herehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/35927168/upload-sql-database-to-google-drive-using-drive-api?noredirect=1#comment59513033_35927168 since you did such a good job helping me with this issue I was hoping you could help me with this new one. thanks