# Upload sql database to google drive using drive api

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I want to upload a database file to Google drive in my android app.

I can back up the database file fine it saves to /sdcard/schoolbinder/backups/notes

I used this website as a start: https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/quickstart/MainActivity.java

this works as is in my app, but it does pictures not files. any idea on how to upload files

Comment: It might be good to have a look at the [api](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-sdk#create_and_open_files_directly_from_the_drive_ui)

Comment: I did the upload part makes no sense to me this code above in my question works in my app it just does pictures instead of files if anybody knows how to minipulate it into doing files ill be all set

Answer (score 0):

The demo you cited already has the sample for choosing a file.

```
/**
 * Create a new file and save it to Drive.
 */
private void saveFileToDrive() {
    // Start by creating a new contents, and setting a callback.
    Log.i(TAG, "Creating new contents.");
    final Bitmap image = mBitmapToSave;
    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
            // If the operation was not successful, we cannot do anything
            // and must
            // fail.
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Failed to create new contents.");
                return;
            }
            // Otherwise, we can write our data to the new contents.
            Log.i(TAG, "New contents created.");
            // Get an output stream for the contents.
            OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
            // Write the bitmap data from it.
            ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapStream);
            try {
                outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.");
            }
            // Create the initial metadata - MIME type and title.
            // Note that the user will be able to change the title later.
            MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setMimeType("image/jpeg").setTitle("Android Photo.png").build();
            // Create an intent for the file chooser, and start it.
            IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                    .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                    .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                    .setInitialDriveContents(result.getDriveContents())
                    .build(mGoogleApiClient);
            try {
                startIntentSenderForResult(
                        intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Failed to launch file chooser.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Its just a matter of calling it. It seems that the demo is calling the Camera app and returning the `Image`. Try to remove the `if` condition in the `onConnected` method and the `saveFileToDrive` should be called and show a File picker.

Comment: it still looks for an image

Comment: in the code you posted above is what I have. I need to convert that to a file

Comment: You can set just mimeType what file you want to pick,   MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setMimeType("image/jpeg").setTitle("Android Photo.png").build();
MimeType can be refer from https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/